# How to log when using foreach (print or futile.logger)

Tags: r, logging, parallel-foreach

I want to use the `foreach` package in conjunction with logging. I usually use the `futile.logger` package. When work is given to the workers logging information is lost (which is strange as you need to indicate to foreach the logging package)

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930112/how-to-log-using-futile-logger-from-within-a-parallel-method-in-r) but it does not use foreach

```
  library(foreach)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  library(futile.logger)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  library(doParallel)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  flog.threshold(DEBUG)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  cluster <- makeCluster(8)
  registerDoParallel(cluster)
  doStuff <- function(input){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    flog.debug('Doing some stuff with %s', input)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    return(input)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  res <- lapply(FUN=doStuff, X=seq(1,8,1))
  # >> this prints                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  res2 <- foreach(input = seq(1,8,1)) %do% doStuff(input)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  # >> this prints
  res3 <- foreach(input = seq(1,8,1), .packages='futile.logger') %dopar% doStuff(input)        
  # >> this does not                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  identical(res,res2) && identical(res,res3)
```

I do not really care about the parallele backend, can be anything, but how can I symply get the logging working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the solution from [How can I print when using %dopar%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078540/6455166): the idea is to use `snow` to set up your cluster, and set `outfile=""` to redirect worker output to master.

```
library(foreach)
library(futile.logger)
library(doParallel)

library(doSNOW)
cluster <- makeCluster(3, outfile="") # I only have 4 cores, but you could do 8
registerDoSNOW(cluster)
flog.threshold(DEBUG)

doStuff <- function(input){
  flog.info('Doing some stuff with %s', input) # change to flog.info
  return(input) 
  } 
res <- lapply(FUN=doStuff, X=seq(1,8,1))
# >> this prints                                                              
res2 <- foreach(input = seq(1,8,1)) %do% doStuff(input) 
# >> this prints
res3 <- foreach(input = seq(1,8,1), .packages='futile.logger') %dopar% doStuff(input)  
# >> this prints too
```

Output:

```
> res3 <- foreach(input = seq(1,8,1), .packages='futile.logger') %dopar% doStuff(input)  
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
INFO [2016-08-08 08:22:39] Doing some stuff with 3
Type: EXEC 
INFO [2016-08-08 08:22:39] Doing some stuff with 1
INFO [2016-08-08 08:22:39] Doing some stuff with 2
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
INFO [2016-08-08 08:22:39] Doing some stuff with 5
INFO [2016-08-08 08:22:39] Doing some stuff with 4
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
INFO [2016-08-08 08:22:39] Doing some stuff with 6
INFO [2016-08-08 08:22:39] Doing some stuff with 7
INFO [2016-08-08 08:22:39] Doing some stuff with 8
```

**Output to log file.** Here's an alternative that outputs to a log file, following [How to log using futile logger from within a parallel method in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20952480/6455166).  It has the advantage of having a cleaner output, but still requires `flog.info`:

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
library(futile.logger)
nworkers <- 3
cluster <- makeCluster(nworkers)
registerDoSNOW(cluster)
loginit <- function(logfile) flog.appender(appender.file(logfile))
foreach(input=rep('~/Desktop/out.log', nworkers), 
  .packages='futile.logger') %dopar% loginit(input)
doStuff <- function(input){
  flog.info('Doing some stuff with %s', input)
  return(input) 
  } 
foreach(input = seq(1,8,1), .packages='futile.logger') %dopar% doStuff(input) 
stopCluster(cluster)
readLines("~/Desktop/out.log")
```

Output:

```
> readLines("~/Desktop/out.log")
[1] "INFO [2016-08-08 10:07:30] Doing some stuff with 2"
[2] "INFO [2016-08-08 10:07:30] Doing some stuff with 1"
[3] "INFO [2016-08-08 10:07:30] Doing some stuff with 3"
[4] "INFO [2016-08-08 10:07:30] Doing some stuff with 4"
[5] "INFO [2016-08-08 10:07:30] Doing some stuff with 5"
[6] "INFO [2016-08-08 10:07:30] Doing some stuff with 6"
[7] "INFO [2016-08-08 10:07:30] Doing some stuff with 7"
[8] "INFO [2016-08-08 10:07:30] Doing some stuff with 8"
```

Comment: The thing with the second method is that you are NOT logging on the console ... Are you ?

Comment: The whole point of using `parallel` is to abstract away from `snow` and `multicore`...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work now. Running on Ubuntu with R 3.4.2. I get no log output to the console at all.